# Javascript Form POST request only working on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, post

So when I click the button on chrome it makes the request and a zip file is downloaded no problem. On Firefox on Windows and Mac it does not work on IE too.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
  <div id="send" class="button" onclick="submitOgreReq(geojsonFeature);     return false">TEST</div>
```

```
var geojsonFeature = {
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
    "name": "Coors Field",
    "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
    "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
}
};

function submitOgreReq(geojson) {

 var f = document.createElement('form')
f.action = 'https://ogre.adc4gis.com/convertJson'
f.method = 'POST'
 var i = document.createElement('input')
i.value = JSON.stringify(geojson)
i.name = "json"
f.appendChild(i)
f.submit()


}
```

Comment: Does it "not work as well" in any quantifiable way, or is it more of an indefinable spiritual malaise?

Comment: No clue why I wrote it like that, does not work at all.

Comment: Well said! I'd run in FF or IE, hit F12, set a breakpoint at the start of `submitOgreReq()`, and step through it to see if/where I get an exception. If it does get through that without a JS exception, Fiddler is a great tool for debugging HTTP traffic: https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Comment: Are you loading this one the same https/domain that you are requesting through JavaScript?  Same Origin Policy would stop you if you are trying to go from http to https, or from one domain to another.

Comment: Nope, im running the script on my home machine and the request is made to an external server.

Comment: When I use Fiddler it only shows up when the request is made from Chrome not from Firefox.